# Is there any way to copy the tooltip text in Firefox? 

Tags: linux, firefox, software-rec, browser-addons

Is there any way to copy the tooltip text in Firefox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Of course, you can ctrl-u and search for the tooltip in the html source or you can make a screen shot, but I guess that's not what you're after.

Comment: Good idea !

Comment: sorry Manni . I found tool for that KaKeeware ToolTip Thief

Comment: +1 to this answer - No Tooltip Timeout 1.0  add-on will show tooltip for long time ;)

Comment: I searched for tooltip by words and found nothing in the source.

Answer (score 2):

When hovering over the desired element, open [the page inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. You can generally see the tooltip text in the console and copy manually (click twice to activate the field) or select "copy" > "inner HTML" from the context menu (right click).

You can also open the inspector from [the Firefox context menu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Context_menu_items), but this option isn't available on [websites which implement their own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage).

Comment: We always appreciate contributions from the community, but can you please elaborate on your answer and cite your source, rather than simply posting one line of "code?"

Comment: @Run5k: There is no source, I discovered this method myself.

Comment: @user598527: Also, this isn't "code"; it's a sequence of actions to take in the GUI. It's a much better answer than the others (including the multiply upvoted accepted one).

Answer (score 1):

[I've seen this trick working with tooltips on some websites](http://mvark.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/2-ways-to-copy-tooltip-text-from-web.html) - select tooltip & its surrounding words, copy selected text while the tooltip text is visible & then paste at the desired location. You'll need to remove the extra words you copied initially.
[image]